# Instanciamento de classe

Tags: java

Ola, criei uma classe vetor e um metodo para somar seus elementos.

Porém, na instanciação do mesmo, nao esta retornando, podem ajudar?

```
public class TesteVetor {

    public static void main(){
        Vetor vetor1 = new Vetor(10);
        Vetor vetor2 = new Vetor(5);

        public int produtoPontos(Vetor v1, Vetor v2) {

            int soma = 0;
            if (v1.getDimensao() == v2.getDimensao()){
            for (int i=0; i<v1.getDimensao(); i++){
            soma += v1.getValores()[i] * v2.getValores()[i];
            }
            return soma;
        }
            else {
            return -1;
        }
        }



        System.out.println ("Soma dos elementos: ", +somar(vetor1));

    }
}
```

------> Classe vetor abaixo:

```
public class Vetor {

    private int dimensao = 0;
    private int[] valores;

    public int getDimensao() {
        return dimensao;
    }

    public void setDimensao(int dimensao) {
        this.dimensao = dimensao;
    }

    public int[] getValores() {
        return valores;
    }

    public Vetor (int dimensao){
        this.dimensao = dimensao;
        this.inicializa();
    }

    public void inicializa (){

        valores = new int[dimensao];

        for (int i=0; i<dimensao; i++){
            valores[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
        }
    }       

    public int somar(Vetor vetor) {
        int soma = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<vetor.getDimensao(); j++){
             soma += vetor.getValores()[j];
        }
        return soma;
    }



}
```

Comment: Seu primeiro erro é na declaração do método main, vc declarou outro método dentro dele.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente seu codigo nao sera compilado por alguns erros na programacao.

Nao entendi muito bem seu objetivo mas espero que esse codigo a ajude:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vetor vetor1 = new Vetor(10);
    Vetor vetor2 = new Vetor(5);
    int soma = produtoPontos(vetor1, vetor2);

    System.out.println(vetor1.somar(vetor1));
    System.out.println(vetor2.somar(vetor2));
    System.out.println("Soma dos elementos: " +soma);

}

public static int produtoPontos(Vetor v1, Vetor v2) {

    int soma = 0;
    if (v1.getDimensao() == v2.getDimensao()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < v1.getDimensao(); i++) {
            soma += v1.getValores()[i] * v2.getValores()[i];
        }
        return soma;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode criar um segundo método dentro do método `main`!
A [resposta do Henrique](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85550/) está muito boa. Mas gostaria de deixar uma outra:
Como os números são inseridos randomicamente você poderia imprimir os números que foram gerados aleatoriamente para poder conferir a soma, ou poderia só inserir os números manualmente  e conferir o processo com os resultados obtidos.

Answer (score 0):

Suas duas classes possuem alguns erros. O primeiro é que você não poderá criar um método dentro de outro método semelhante a algumas linguagens, como o Delphi.

Outra coisa é dividir as responsabilidades dentre os objetos, ou seja, a sua classe Vetor está responsável por inicializar o vetor e também somar os mesmos. O ideal é que a classe Vetor somente seja responsável por armazenar os valores referentes ao Vetor, ou seja, a *dimensão* e o *valor*. Seguindo, não totalmente, a especificação dos JavaBeans.

O seu método *somar(Vetor vetor)...* está recebendo um objeto do tipo Vetor na mesma classe, ou seja, você está passando ele mesmo para ele mesmo (meio confuso não?). Fiz um pequeno exemplo, melhorando um pouquinho, espero que você entenda o código:

Classe Principal:

```
public class TesteVetor {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TesteVetor();
    }

    public TesteVetor(){
        Vetor vetor1 = new Vetor(10);
        Vetor vetor2 = new Vetor(5);

        System.out.println("Soma dos elementos: " +somar(vetor1));
        System.out.println("Soma dos elementos: " +somar(vetor2));

        System.out.println("ProdutosPontos(): " + produtoPontos(vetor1, vetor2));
    }

    public int produtoPontos(Vetor v1, Vetor v2) {
        int soma = 0;

        if (v1.getDimensao() == v2.getDimensao()){
            for (int i = 0; i < v1.getDimensao(); i++) {
               soma += v1.getValores()[i] * v2.getValores()[i];
            }

            return soma;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }


    //Pode jogar este método aqui, tirando a responsabilidade da classe Vetor:
    public int somar(Vetor vetor) {
        int soma = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<vetor.getDimensao(); j++){
            soma += vetor.getValores()[j];
        }
        return soma;
    } }
```

Classe Vetor:

```
public class Vetor {

private int dimensao = 0;
private int[] valores;

//Construtor:
public Vetor (int dimensao){
    this.dimensao = dimensao;
    inicializa();
}

public int getDimensao() {
    return dimensao;
}

public void setDimensao(int dimensao) {
    this.dimensao = dimensao;
}

public int[] getValores() {
    return valores;
}

//Ideal é tirar esse método e "jogar" na classe TesteVetor:
public void inicializa(){
    valores = new int[dimensao];

    for (int i=0; i<dimensao; i++){
        valores[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
    }
}  }
```